# How to make default owner for all files and directories in folder

Tags: linux, setuid

I want all new files created in one folder to have an owner called user1

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In FreeBSD exist suiddir(http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount&sektion=8). You may mount partitions with suiddir option and add 4000 permissions.

In linux GFS2 support suiddir. Also you may use cron or inotify, to change file owner.

Comment: And what about dir not being a mountpoint?

Comment: sorry but i diddnt get how can i use it

Comment: bindbn's answer is correct but terse.

There is no easy way to implement what you want on Linux - the setuid bit does not act like the setgid bit any of the standard filesystems.

FreeBSD (and Linux using only the GFS2 filesystem) support a suiddir mount option that makes the setuid bit act like the setgid bit on directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can have "all files belong to a group", by **chmod g+s dir**

If this doesn`t fit your needs, you have to deal with ACL and a default mask.

Answer (score 0):

Hai
Linux always associates a file or directory with a user and a group. For example, assume I have a file named webmaster.txt in my home directory. If I run the command ls -l webmaster.txt, I get the following result:
-rw-rw-r- 1 root root 1024 Feb 21 15:10 example.txt

Here I think your 
directory is /root/test 
file is example.txt 
user is user1 & group is user1

If you want to change permission, gust follow the instruction

**chown -R user1.user1 /root/test/**

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

Although all the documentation seems to say otherwise, the sticky bit seems to do it to an extent.

e.g.  to preserve the parent directory group.

```
chmod g+s [directory name]
```

Now any files or directories created within this directory inherit the parent group.

Not sure if this will be enough.  Usually it's the owner/group of the current user or process that sets these.